# Is there any way to go directly to a specific case?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there was any simple way one could "jump" directly to a specific case.

I know it can be done by using a do while loop. Was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

for example (not the whole code of course):

```
.
.
.
case 8:
            {
                if (grades.findStudent(tempid1)==-1)
                {
                    cout << "\nOne of the ID's you have entered wasn't found. Try again.\n" << endl;
                    case(8); //<- <- <- something like that
                }

            }
            break;
.
.
.
```

Comment: Well, there is `goto`... but maybe there is a better way to structure your code instead.

Comment: Ahh!! swich-case for this purpose only Am I wrong,,Are you using break; statements

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more context? maybe we can suggest a better way than jumping from case to case

Comment: @cdhowie Never the evil `goto`! It has so many subtle but deadly problems that can occur being directly called in C++ (this isn't as true in C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Do:

```
switch (...) {
    case 1:
        foo ();
        goto bar;
    case 2:
        ...

    bar:
    case 42:
        baz ();
        break;
}
```

But there might exist other solutions to your problem.

Comment: @Misch I'm looking around my office in complete shock that I don't have that printed and taped to my wall.  Brb.

Comment: You should really note that very damaging events can occur from incorrect `goto` placement in C++ which an inexperienced C++ programmer would not know about.

Comment: I'd avoid this. This is going to make your code much harder to understand for others and even you in the long term. If you just need a case to fall through to the next, restructure the code so that it can naturally do it. If there are multiple such combinations, consider whether a loop makes sense or whether you can just factor out the code to different functions that can be reused.

Comment: @Pyrce: Indeed, especially inside switch-case statements.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I'd avoid this too. If OP had given us the whole switch loop (or a stub thereof), we'd have pointed out to some more appropriate construct. Here, I just answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...

I'd think that the #1 best way to restructure this would be to make whatever is in `case 8:` a function, and simply call that function within `case 8:` and where ever else you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong control structure here. You want something like:

```
int studentId;
while(true) {
    studentId = getStudentId();  // Sorry, I'm rusty.
    if (isValid(studentId)) { break;}
}
switch (...) {
    ...
}
```

Do one thing at a time.  You're not the Duff of *Duff's Device*.  Look that one up.  It's scary!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would be better

```
case 8:
   while (grades.findStudent(tempid1)==-1)
   {
      cout << "\nOne of the ID's you have entered wasn't found. Try again.\n" << endl;
      // Do whatever to enter tempid1 (perhaps a function here that is used
      // before the start of this switch statement?
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't KNOW, but I suspect this is some kind of "menu-system", and 8 is "search for student".

In which case you want to do:

```
            while (grades.findStudent(tempid1)==-1)
            {
                cout << "\none of the ID's you have entered wasn't found. Try again.\n" << endl;
                // add code to ask for tempid1 again
            }
```

So, instead of using "if", you use "while".